# JSON and SQLite3 in Python

Tags: python, json, api, sqlite

I'm currently trying to parse the following small sample lines from a JSON dataset.  However, in python I'm running into issues.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  My poor attempt at the code is below:

Dataset:

```
{
   "matchId": 1778839570,
   "region": "NA",
   "platformId": "NA1",
   "matchMode": "CLASSIC",
   "matchType": "MATCHED_GAME",
   "matchCreation": 1427867835805,
   "matchDuration": 3424,
   "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
   "mapId": 11,
   "season": "SEASON2015",
   "matchVersion": "5.6.0.194",
   "participants": [
      {
         "teamId": 100,
         "spell1Id": 4,
         "spell2Id": 11,
         "championId": 113,
         "highestAchievedSeasonTier": "GOLD"
      }
   ]
}
```

Code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
fhand = json.load(open('riot.json'))
for e in fhand:
    print e
```

Note: The idea is to parse each one of these as a column, where the matchID will be a key_id for a sql table (distinct).  The other tuples will be columns with values.  In reality, there'll be numerous blocks of text like the above Dataset, and each one will correspond to a matchID.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: And what is your question? ("Write the code for me!" is not question.) See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Apologies!  The question is, how do I parse that JSON set and insert it into a sqlite3 database.  Thanks for the helpful tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `fhand` is a dictionary. Take a look at python dictionary's documentation: [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for how to use dictionary.

```
for e in fhand:
    print e
```

this code will print all the keys (or the column names).

```
for e in fhand:
    print fhand[e]
```

You can get the values by using this. Also there are other builtin functions which can be used here. Check the documentation for choosing the right one for you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick repsonse!  I went through some of the documentation.  The code you replied with is a little different.  Do you know why it doesn't follow this pattern?                                                       >>> for i, v in enumerate(['tic', 'tac', 'toe']):
...     print i, v
...
0 tic
1 tac
2 toe

Comment: You have to read a lot.  enumerate documentation :https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  Enumerate in this other stackoverflow example thread was used to make an (index_position, value) tuple.

Comment: Just did.  Sorry, new to stackoverflow and trying to get the hang of it :)  Thanks again!

Comment: do you know how to parse the inner list of tuples under participants?  I tried the similar trick with the dictionary parsing you recommended.  However, it's parsing the literal string "participants."  I want to be able to parse the inner dictionary (that's inside a list, effectively causing it to be a list of tuples).  Unfortunately, JSON's format is this inner list.